# For loop to update NSTableView

Tags: objective-c

Please forgive me for the post, I am at a brick wall and cannot work this out, so any, any help at all would be highly appreciated.

I have the following for loop code snippet:

```
for (int i=0; i<noOfColumns; i++)
{

    tCol = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title"]];

    [[tCol headerCell] setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Column"]];
    [myTableView addTableColumn:tCol];
}
```

The problem is that i need to change "Title" to other keys like "id", "First_name", "Surname", "Address" etc.

```
stringWithFormat:@"Title"
```

how can I update stringWithFormat: @""; in this for loop?

The first time the loop runs picks up "Title" then second time the loop runs it picks up "First_Name" in the for loop.

Ive spent the last 3 hours trying to work this out along with learning NS

I am trying to update an NSTableView with an array coming from JSON. If I change "Title" to other keys received in JSON, I can update the NSTableView, however every column is the "Title" and not the other keys returned in the JSON.

Thank you for reading and if you can provide any help at all, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you take my advice in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960691/save-json-response-in-nstableview)? Populating a table view is quite basic stuff. You can design everything in Interface Builder, there is no need to create the table view programmatically. And do **not** use a cell based table view.

Comment: I would recommend that you go through a tutorial about Objective-C. You are missing basics like naming conventions.

SO is not an interactive tutorial. You will not get the expected result from the guys on SO.

Comment: The other advice is good but if you insist on this approach, you can create an array of column names. Then access them in the loop;    tCol = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:columnIdentifiers[i]];